# Cordova: java.io.IOException in cordova-plugin-video-editor

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am using cordova-plugin-video-editor plugin to get video thumbnail.

But whenever I run function `VideoEditor.createThumbnail()...` It produces following error: 
 `java.io.IOException` and nothing works.

I think it happens in latest android versions because this issue happened in Samsung Galaxy S5 ( Android Version 6.0.2 ). But It worked fine in 5.1.1.

Why is this issue happening and how can we resolve this issue?

I'll appreciate any contribution.

Thanks